# How to sort an HTML table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I have a table that contains numbers, dates, and strings. I want to be able to sort them by clicking on the table's headings and have them sort by the particular clicked on heading, but I am having trouble with the logic to do this. I have read other stack overflow answers but they are somewhat confusing as to what I am supposed to do. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Function 

 const sorted = () => {
        const arr = []
        const tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName('table')
        const tableRow = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
        const tableHeader = document.querySelectorAll('th');
        console.log(tableBody)

        for (let i = 0; i < tableHeader.length; i++) {
            tableHeader[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log(tableBody)
            })
        }

    }
    sorted()

Table

 <div className="outputs" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Stock Name</th>
                        <th>Price Of Option</th>
                        <th>Number Of Options</th>
                        <th>Total Amount Spent</th>
                        <th>Option Sold At</th>
                        <th>Amount Of Options Sold</th>
                        <th>Proft</th>
                    </tr>
                    {listOfOptions.map(option => {
                        return (
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{option.clock}</td>
                                    <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                                    <td>${option.price}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                                    <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                    <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it -

- add handler on each  or one  that wrapps all
- in handler get name of column and sort listOfOptions by this name (before it, map column name to key, ex: Price Of Option -> price, etc...)
- use hooks (useState) or setState to set new sortedArray to state and rerender component

Answer (score 0):

The steps to take are:

1. Store the array in a local variable `listOfOptions`
2. Attach click handlers to the header elements of the table
3. Within these handlers, sort the arrays and replace the old array with the new sorted arrays.

I have only implemented two header click handlers, but it should be enough to get the general idea.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [listOfOptions, setListOfOptions] = useState([
    {
      clock: "23/12/2020",
      name: "Dorothy",
      price: 12.34,
      amountOfOptions: 1,
      totalAmountSpent: 23.3232,
      optionPriceSoldAt: 34.22323,
      amountOfOptionsSold: 122.34,
      totalProfit: 44433.343
    },
    {
      clock: "23/12/2020",
      name: "Brian",
      price: 12.34,
      amountOfOptions: 2,
      totalAmountSpent: 255.3232,
      optionPriceSoldAt: 52.194323,
      amountOfOptionsSold: 622.34,
      totalProfit: 9433.343
    },
    {
      clock: "23/12/2020",
      name: "Alfred",
      price: 12.34,
      amountOfOptions: 3,
      totalAmountSpent: 123.3232,
      optionPriceSoldAt: 12.22323,
      amountOfOptionsSold: 72.34,
      totalProfit: 5433.343
    }
  ]);

  function sortByNumberOfOptions() {
    const clonedOptions = [...listOfOptions];

    clonedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.amountOfOptions  - b.amountOfOptions;
    });

    setListOfOptions(clonedOptions);
  }

  function sortByName() {
    const clonedOptions = [...listOfOptions];

    clonedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    setListOfOptions(clonedOptions);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="outputs">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th onClick={sortByName}>Stock Name</th>
            <th>Price Of Option</th>
            <th onClick={sortByNumberOfOptions}>Number Of Options</th>
            <th>Total Amount Spent</th>
            <th>Option Sold At</th>
            <th>Amount Of Options Sold</th>
            <th>Proft</th>
          </tr>

          <tbody>
            {listOfOptions.map((option, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{option.clock}</td>
                  <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                  <td>${option.price}</td>
                  <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                  <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                  <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                  <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                  <td
                    style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? "green" : "red" }}
                  >
                    ${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

StackBlitz version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-array-with-react?file=src/App.js)